# After setting the World Extent to the Map still we can move the map while drag

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers-3

I am taking the world extent as below

```
var myextent = ol.proj.transformExtent([-180, -85, 180, 85], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

And setting it to the Map to restrict the zoom, below is the ol.View object created

```
view : new ol.View({
                    center : center.getCoordinates(),
                    extent : myextent,
                    zoom : this.mapOptions.zoom,
                    minZoom: 2,
                })
```

If we use mouse wheel we zoom is not happening beyond the extent, but we can drag and see the map out of the extent.

How can i restrict the extent from drag also?

Answer (score 1):

There is no restricted extent functionality in OpenLayers 3 right now. There have been some discussions such as: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/2777